# How to transfer data from a spinner in an activity to multiple fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to android developing and this is a project that I'm doing. I have very little knowledge on programming.

So I would like to transfer data from the val *selectedStudent* which is from an onselect from a spinner to multiple fragments which I'm using fragment Navigation for. Is there anybody who can guide me? Here is the code for now. I can't seem to find one that works for kotlin. Or is there a better way to do this?

[Image of how the code would work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lJqj.png)

There is a bottom navigation that would switch between fragments. The Student's name will be selected from an array and it would retrieve data from that name and display the data in the individual fragments.

**Code in activity**

```
class NPIS_StudentDataHome : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var nameTest = arrayOf("Jessica", "Adams", "Why")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.npis_studentdatahome)

        val npisBottomNav= findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.npisBottomNav)
        val navController= findNavController(R.id.npisStudentFragmentNav)

        npisBottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)

        val adapter= ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,nameTest)

        studentDataSpinner.adapter=adapter

        studentDataSpinner.onItemSelectedListener=object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedStudent:String=nameTest[position]
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"$selectedStudent's Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                
            }
```

**Code in Fragment**

```
class logFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use Android MVVM architecture with a viewmodel shared between activity and fragments:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel